# How to put your experience as a freelancer in your CV for PhD?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, cv

How to put your experience as a freelancer in your CV for a PhD application?

Specifically, I am looking for a title to choose for the section in which I want to write about this experience. Is it appropriate to put it in a section titled "professional experiences"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Experiences" is too passive. You "experience" the sunset. Make it more active. Professional Activities. Consulting, perhaps. Independent Research Activities. Other Professional Work.

Comment: The thing that I have doubt about is that can I consider being a freelancer  a professional activity? Maybe "work activities" can be a good alternative. What do you think?

Comment: If you earn money from the work then it is professional, I'd guess.